# Read XML from MySQL Database into PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML structure stored in my database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Payouts>
<Range end="1" start="1">900</Range>
<Range end="2" start="2">650</Range>     
<Range end="3" start="3">450</Range>     
<Range end="4" start="4">330</Range>     
<Range end="5" start="5">230</Range>     
<Range end="6" start="6">175</Range>     
<Range end="7" start="7">120</Range>     
<Range end="8" start="8">95</Range>     
<Range end="9" start="9">80</Range>     
<Range end="10" start="10">70</Range>     
<Range end="15" start="11">50</Range>     
<Range end="20" start="16">35</Range>     
<Range end="25" start="21">25</Range>     
<Range end="30" start="26">18</Range>     
<Range end="40" start="31">15</Range>     
<Range end="50" start="41">14</Range>     
<Range end="75" start="51">13</Range>     
<Range end="100" start="76">12</Range>     
<Range end="125" start="100">11</Range>     
<Range end="150" start="126">10</Range>     
<Range end="200" start="151">9</Range>     
<Range end="350" start="201">8</Range>     
<Range end="360" start="351">7</Range>     
<Range end="380" start="361">6</Range>   
<Range end="400" start="381">5</Range>   
<Range end="420" start="401">4</Range>   
<Range end="440" start="421">3</Range>   
<Range end="460" start="441">2</Range>   
<Range end="480" start="461">1</Range>   
<Range end="500" start="481">1</Range>   
<Range end="520" start="501">1</Range>   
</Payouts>
```

This is basically a range of options. I'd like to filter through these results and get the value in the end and start and then display the value for that row.

The output would be something like the following:

`1st - 900
2nd - 650
3rd - 450
4th - 330
5th - 230
6th - 175
7th - 120
8th - 95
9th - 80
10th - 70
11th to 15th - 50
16th to 20th - 35
21th to 25th - 25`

I tried to read the XML file with the following code:

```
$payout_xml = $event_details[0]['PAYOUT_DETAILS'];
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($payout_xml);
echo "The Simple Element is: ".print_r($xml);
echo 'single value: <br />';
echo $xml->Payouts->Range->end; // get single value
echo "end of data";
```

When I `print_r` the `$payout_xml` I get the following results:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[Range] => Array
    (
        [0] => 900
        [1] => 650
        [2] => 450
        [3] => 330
        [4] => 230
        [5] => 175
        [6] => 120
        [7] => 95
        [8] => 80
        [9] => 70
        [10] => 50
        [11] => 35
        [12] => 25
        [13] => 18
        [14] => 15
        [15] => 14
        [16] => 13
        [17] => 12
        [18] => 11
        [19] => 10
        [20] => 9
        [21] => 8
        [22] => 7
        [23] => 6
        [24] => 5
        [25] => 4
        [26] => 3
        [27] => 2
        [28] => 1
        [29] => 1
        [30] => 1
    )

)
The Simple Element is: 1
```

I'm not accessing the data though. How can I do this?

Comment: please show your entire code that is necessary to get the data from the database and the output you get.

Comment: Can you try printing both `$event_details[0]['PAYOUT_DETAILS']` & `$xml` to make sure they actually contain data?

Comment: Johannes and love I updated the question with the output of those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`end` is an attribute, not an element. Try something like:

```
echo $sxml->Range . '|' . $sxml->Range['end'] . '|' . $sxml->Range['start'];
```

which will give the output as

> 900|1|1

Functional example

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Payouts>
<Range end="1" start="1">900</Range>
<Range end="2" start="2">650</Range>     
<Range end="3" start="3">450</Range>     
<Range end="4" start="4">330</Range>     
<Range end="5" start="5">230</Range>     
<Range end="6" start="6">175</Range>     
<Range end="7" start="7">120</Range>     
<Range end="8" start="8">95</Range>     
<Range end="9" start="9">80</Range>     
<Range end="10" start="10">70</Range>     
<Range end="15" start="11">50</Range>     
<Range end="20" start="16">35</Range>     
<Range end="25" start="21">25</Range>     
<Range end="30" start="26">18</Range>     
<Range end="40" start="31">15</Range>     
<Range end="50" start="41">14</Range>     
<Range end="75" start="51">13</Range>     
<Range end="100" start="76">12</Range>     
<Range end="125" start="100">11</Range>     
<Range end="150" start="126">10</Range>     
<Range end="200" start="151">9</Range>     
<Range end="350" start="201">8</Range>     
<Range end="360" start="351">7</Range>     
<Range end="380" start="361">6</Range>   
<Range end="400" start="381">5</Range>   
<Range end="420" start="401">4</Range>   
<Range end="440" start="421">3</Range>   
<Range end="460" start="441">2</Range>   
<Range end="480" start="461">1</Range>   
<Range end="500" start="481">1</Range>   
<Range end="520" start="501">1</Range>   
</Payouts>';
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $sxml->Range . '|' . $sxml->Range['end'] . '|' . $sxml->Range['start']; // get single value
```

Demo: https://eval.in/583665

or if you want to iterate through all records, https://eval.in/583666.

```
foreach($sxml->Range as $range){
     echo $range . '|' . $range['end'] . '|' . $range['start'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is really good. How would I loop through this results for each Range? Nevermind...you already updated your answer.